# Passing column name into function

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, non-standard-evaluation

I have a simple problem with non-standard evaluation: passing a variable name as an argument into a function.

As a reproducible example, here's a simple thing: taking the mean of one variable, `mpg` from the `mtcars` dataset. My end goal is to have a function where I can input the dataset and the variable, and get the mean.

So without a function:

```r
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% summarise(mean = mean(mpg))

#>       mean
#> 1 20.09062
```

I've tried to use `get()` for non-standard evaluation, but I'm getting errors:

```r
library(tidyverse)
summary_stats <- function(variable, dataframe){
  dataframe %>% summarise(mean = get(variable))
}

summary_stats(mpg, mtcars)

#> Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `mean`.
#> x invalid first argument
#> ℹ Input `mean` is `get(variable)`.
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

### Edit:

I also had one additional follow-up question.

I also need the `variable` argument as a `char` string, I tried the code below, but I'm still missing how to do that:

```r
library(tidyverse)
summary_stats <- function(variable, dataframe){
  dataframe %>% summarise(mean = mean({{variable}}))
  print(as.character({{variable}}))
}

summary_stats(disp, mtcars)
#> Error in print(as.character({: object 'disp' not found
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Here's the dplyr vignette that you'll find helpful for stuff like tidyeval => https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html

Comment: For anyone reading this question in the future, @theairbend3r 's link is exactly the sort of documentation that steps through the answer, and is just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the curly-curly (`{{}}`) operator to pass column name as unquoted variable.

To get variables passed as character value we can use `deparse`, `substitute`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

summary_stats <- function(variable, dataframe){
  print(deparse(substitute(variable)))
  dataframe %>% summarise(mean = mean({{variable}}))
}
```

```
#[1] "mpg"

#      mean
#1 20.09062
```

Comment: I also had a follow up question (in the edit above) if you're able to help. Thank you so much.

Comment: We can use `deparse`, `substitute` for that. See updated answer.